remove showcaseview package target widget square
I use showcaseview and wanted to remove the square that is by default on the target widget as shown in the screenshot below:
[
I don't think it is something the package offers but I am wondering if there is a solution to do so.
Any idea is appreciated.

Better to understand with code, share your code which you have tried.

I mean the code is the package code, I added nothing, this square gets added by the package if you take a look at the example they have you will understand.
